# what is the alternative for convertion of string to int[ ] without using LINQ code in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert string to int [] like

I am having a string "123456" and I am trying to convert this to "1","2","3","4","5","6".

I am able to perform the action using LINQ code but I am not supposed to use it in my program please refer my program below and suggest me the appropriate methods to convert string to array integer.

The below code is C# code please refer and give me the alternate methods to convert string to integer array in c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sum_of_given_charecters
{
    public partial class aharrepaddusmanualfunctions : Form
    {
        public aharrepaddusmanualfunctions()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        internal static Form cs()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //Replacing Charecters as per requirement.
        public string replace1(string repstr1)
        {
            string str1 = Regex.Replace(repstr1, @"[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
            repstr1.Replace(" ", "").Replace("`", "").Replace("~", "").Replace("!", "")
                             .Replace("@", "").Replace("#", "").Replace("$", "").Replace("%", "").Replace("^", "")
                             .Replace("&", "").Replace("*", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "")
                             .Replace("_", "").Replace("=", "").Replace("+", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "")
                             .Replace("|", "").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(";", "")
                             .Replace("'", "").Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("?", "")
                             .Replace(@"\", "").Replace(@"""", "")
                             .Replace(">", "").Replace("<", "").Replace("1", "").Replace("2", "").Replace("3", "")
                             .Replace("4", "").Replace("5", "").Replace("6", "").Replace("7", "").Replace("8", "")
                             .Replace("9", "").Replace("0", "");
            string str2 = str1.ToUpper();
            string word1 = str2.Replace("A", "1").Replace("B", "2").Replace("C", "3").Replace("D", "4").Replace("E", "5").Replace("F", "8")
                             .Replace("G", "3").Replace("H", "5").Replace("I", "1").Replace("J", "1").Replace("K", "2").Replace("L", "3")
                             .Replace("M", "4").Replace("N", "5").Replace("O", "7").Replace("P", "8").Replace("Q", "1").Replace("R", "2")
                             .Replace("S", "3").Replace("T", "4").Replace("U", "6").Replace("V", "6").Replace("W", "6").Replace("X", "5")
                             .Replace("Y", "1").Replace("Z", "7");
            return word1;
        }

        //Function for adding
        public static string add1(string addval)
        {
            //int[] y = new int[addval.Length];
            //for (int i = 0; i < addval.Length; i++)
            //{
            //    y[i] = int.Parse(addval[i]);
            //}
            int[] y = addval.Select(o => o - 48).ToArray();
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < addval.Length; i++)
            {
                sum = sum + y[i];
            }
            string addva = sum.ToString();
            return addva;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Printing the given Text...........................................................................
            string str = textBox1.Text;
            res.Text = ("Result");
            yhe.Text = ("You have Entered");
            c1.Text = (":");
            lryhe.Text = str.ToString();
            // Replacing characters as per requirement by calling my function....................................
            string str2 = replace1(str);
            //Displaying sum of charecters.......................................................................
            soc.Text = ("Sum of Charecters");
            c2.Text = (":");
            string str3 = add1(str2);
            rsoc.Text = str3.ToString();
            //displaying sum of sum.............................................................................
            sv.Text = ("Summed Value");
            c3.Text = (":");
            string str4 = add1(str3);

            // label10.Text = str4.ToString();
            if (str4.Length > 1)
            {
                string str5 = add1(str4);
                rsv.Text = str5.ToString();
            }
            else if (str4.Length == 1)
            {
                if (str4 == "0")
                {
                    rsv.Text = "Sum is Zero";
                }
                else
                {
                    rsv.Text = str4.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will they always be single digit numbers?

Comment: Please don't label C# code as if it were a Javascript snippet. You've posted a lot of code here, most of which seems to be irrelevant to what you're trying to do. Please post a [mcve], ideally as a console app with hard-coded input (we don't need a GUI), along with what you've tried so far. Additionally, now would be a good time to start following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: What's wrong with using the index property on the string?

Comment: A string is already an array of char. Loop and convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through all of the `char`acters and ensure they are between `'0'//0x30` and `'9'//0x39` :

`List<int> result = new List<int>(); // as suggested by` [@GSP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4311859/gsp)

```
foreach(char c in meString)
{
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        result.Add((int)(c - 0x30));
}

// then to copy to array :
int[] arr = new int[result.Count];
result.CopyTo(arr);
```

[Check this online](http://rextester.com/CWON43322)

Comment: Because you use `if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')`, I think `List<int> arr` is better. Finally, convert arr to an array.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this for the conversion as the string is already an array that you can index:

```
int[] myArray = new int[myString.Length]();    
for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++ )
{
    myArray[i] = (int)myString[i] - 48;
}
```